# Laravel validation if both field are empty then error . But if one is null then other is required

Tags: laravel, validation, rules

I am trying to make a rule if one is empty or not present then other is required but if both are not present then it give error.
I have used this but if both are empty then it not give any error

```
'inventory_storage_container_id'        => 'required_if:inventory_storage_space_id,=,null|integer|exists:inventory_storage_containers,id',
'inventory_storage_space_id'            => 'required_if:inventory_storage_container_id,=,null|integer|exists:inventory_storage_spaces,id',
```

What i have to do ? This is a different scenario if i not include both field in request body it not give any error but i need an error if both are empty . This topic is not duplicate .

Answer (score 2):

try [`required_without`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-without)

```
'inventory_storage_container_id'        => 'required_without:inventory_storage_space_id|integer|exists:inventory_storage_containers,id',
'inventory_storage_space_id'            => 'required_without:inventory_storage_container_id|integer|exists:inventory_storage_spaces,id',
```

Comment: Still it passing the rule if both are not present in the request. I think i need to handle it on controller side not in validation rule .

Comment: @MajidJavaid Can I see the controller?

Comment: I am asking if no rule for this then i need to handle it on controller side ?

Comment: Your case can handle with Laravel validation, you don't need to do it at the controller.

Comment: @MajidJavaid this answer is correct. If it's not working for you then you must be doing something incorrectly when sending or checking your input

Comment: Request body

{
  "is_used_on_ar": true,
  "parent_inventory_storage_container_id": 0
}


Output
{
    "status_code": 422,
    "error_code": "invalid_request",
    "error_message": "There are validation errors",
    "fields": {
        "parent_inventory_storage_container_id": [
            "The selected parent inventory storage container id is invalid."
        ]
    }
}

Comment: Not getting any error related to missing fields.

Comment: @MajidJavaid `parent_inventory_storage_container_id` is not mentioned in your question at all. How are you performing the validation?

Comment: @apokryfos If i remove integer and add null for both fields then it give error but if I remove field from body then it not give any error.

Comment: @apokryfos I am applying check on these two fields. If both present or one

Comment: class StartInventoryItemPlacementRequest extends ApiRequest{
 public function rules(): array{
 return [ 'inventory_storage_container_id'        => 'required_without:inventory_storage_space_id|exists:inventory_storage_containers,id',
  'inventory_storage_space_id'            => 'required_without:inventory_storage_container_id|exists:inventory_storage_spaces,id', 'parent_inventory_storage_container_id' => 'integer|exists:inventory_storage_containers,id',
            'is_used_on_ar'                         => 'required|bool',
        ];
    }
}

@MohamedGamalEldin I am using this

Comment: Can you explain something please, what is `ApiRequest`?, should be `extends FormRequest`, there is something custom you do with `ApiRequest`?

Comment: Can you try the default please `use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;` `class StartInventoryItemPlacementRequest extends FormRequest` and `authorize()` function returns true If works the problem comes from `ApiRequest`